# Could once `max_standby_archive_delay` and `max_standby_streaming_delay` with value -1 can cause replication stop on heavy loads?

Tags: postgresql, replication, amazon-rds

In my replication servers on a postgresql master-slave replication scheme on aws RDS I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 7 ERROR:  canceling statement due to conflict with recovery
```

The cause, as far as I understood is that the replication happens simirary like a database migration. A sequence of queries is written something called WAL and then are being executed in a FIFO sequence.

Also, I understood that once you execute queries whilst wal is being executed it can cause conflicts because sometimes the query that is currently is being executed can cause fetching stale data.

So according to [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/runtime-config-replication.html) there are delays that allow first the current queries to be executed and then apply wal changes. Theese are:

1. `max_standby_archive_delay`
2. `max_standby_streaming_delay`

But setting these values as -1 on heavy queries (query execution time >30s) will cause the replicas to have stale data for extended period of times?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is the idea. In the case of a replication conflict PostgreSQL has only two options:

1. cancel the query
2. delay the application of replicated changes.

Setting `max_standby_streaming_delay` to -1 will delay replication indefinitely long.

There are ways to reduce replication conflicts:

- Set `hot_standby_feedback = on` to remove replication conflicts caused by `VACUUM`. **The price you are paying is that long running queries on the standby can bloat your tables.**
- Don't have any statements like `DROP TABLE`, `TRUNCATE`, `ALTER TABLE` and similar in your workload that cause `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` locks.
- In PostgreSQL v12, you can set

  ```
  ALTER TABLE atable SET (vacuum_truncate = off);
  ```

  to disable autovacuum truncation (which also causes a short `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock). In older versions, there is only the crude and undocumented workaround of setting `old_snapshot_threshold` to something else than the default value.

This is all complicated and may have undesired effects, so the **best advice** is this: If you want a standby that does not lag more than necessary, but you also want to run long running queries on a standby server, you should use two standby servers, one for each of these conflicting purposes.

Comment: So in case that I set the `hot_standby_feedback` with value `on` can I have a sceduled job in order to manuall vacumm old and stale values on a sceduled time that I expect my database to have minimum load?

Comment: Also, how does `hot_standby_feedback` and why it can cause to have bloated tables (tables with data to be removed but not deleted yet)? Furthermore, will this setting be applied on each replica?

Comment: `hot_standby_feedback` is a setting on the standby, so you have to set it on the standby where you don't want queries to be canceled. If enabled, autovacuum simply doesn't remove old row versions that might still be needed by long running queries on the standby. Not removing old row versions will bloat the table. Running regular scheduled `VACUUM`s will reduce the number of autovacuum runs, but not necessarily to zero (on small, busy tables).

Comment: Also, if I slighly increace the both the values `max_standby_archive_delay` and `max_standby_streaming_delay` for example instead of `30s` let us say 1minute (`60s`) would have any positive effect alongside with `hot_standby_feedback`?

Comment: Depends on your definition of positive. As I wrote, you'll always have some difficulties if you try to use one standby server for both high availability and queries. Do yourself a favor and use two standby servers.

Comment: Once the long-running queries finish will the unwanted rows of my tables will the records on my master server be auto-vacumed ? Once I set the `hot_standby_feedback` into on value?

Comment: Sure, as soon as the query is finished, replication will catch up, and old tuples will be vacuumed away. But the table may already be bloated by then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103502/discussion-between-dimitrios-desyllas-and-laurenz-albe).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Does that mean setting `max_standby_streaming_delay=-1` is the same as `hot_standby_feedback=on`?

Comment: @JohnStrood No, it is quite different. `hot_standby_feedback=on` *avoids* replication conflicts that arise from `VACUUM` deleting rows. `max_standby_streaming_delay` determines what happens if a replication conflict occurs: the setting -1 will delay WAL replay as long as needed, so that queries on the standby are never canceled.