# Manually VACUUM bloated tables once `hot_standby_feedback` is on on postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

As seen in this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/257751/118215) by setting postgresql's `hot_standby_feedback` on it may cause having bloated table on long running queries. Therefore, in case that size goes out of control (my database consumes way too much space because of dead rows) to be able to handle it.

Therefore, I thought to enforce a `VACCUMM` action in this situation to delete stale and unused rows in case that storage goes out of controll as immediate action.

But how I can VACUUM all the tables of my database manually? Also, how I can make a dedicated user that is able only to `VACUUM` in order to create custom scripts that I can run in these situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `hot_standby_feedback = on`, a manual `VACUUM` won't delete the dead row versions if there is a long running query on the standby.

The only way to do that would be to set `old_snapshot_threshold` to a value different from the default value. Then `VACUUM` (and autovacuum) will remove dead tuples even if an old transaction might still need them. Note that that would defy the purpose of `hot_standby_feedback`, as then the long running query might receive a `snapshot too old` error.